# How do I extract chart back end data from website?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to extract back end data of a chart on the following link - https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/map.html.

On the right hand corner you will see an yellow bubble chart which plots total number of corona virus cases by country. I need to extract the back end data from chart. I did some online research an came across this website - https://onlinejournalismblog.com/2017/05/10/how-to-find-data-behind-chart-map-using-inspector/. It was quite helpful for me and I could get a weblink, which, when I put on my browser I see the back end data in JSON format.

Eg:https://services9.arcgis.com/N9p5hsImWXAccRNI/arcgis/rest/services/Nc2JKvYFoAEOFCG5JSI6/FeatureServer/4/query?f=json&where=(Confirmed%3C%3E0)%20AND%20(Country_Region%3D%27Finland%27)&returnGeometry=false&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=OBJECTID%2CConfirmed%2CLast_Update&orderByFields=Last_Update%20asc&outSR=102100&resultOffset=0&resultRecordCount=1000&cacheHint=true - this is the link for JSON data for Finland.

I tried extracting the data in couple of ways like -

```
url = "..above link.."
x <- fromJSON(url)
x <- GET(url)
```

Everytime, I received error.

I need to extract the back end data of this chart for all countries.

Thank you for your help in advance.

#

```
# Error I get from 
print(x) 

Response [https://services9.arcgis.com/N9p5hsImWXAccRNI/arcgis/rest/services/Nc2JKvYFoAEOFCG5JSI6/FeatureServer/4/query?f=json&where=(Confirmed%3C%3E0)%20AND%20(Country_Region%3D%27Senegal%27)&returnGeometry=false&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=OBJECTID%2CConfirmed%2CLast_Update&orderByFields=Last_Update%20asc&outSR=102100&resultOffset=0&resultRecordCount=1000&cacheHint=true]
  Date: 2020-03-27 14:15
  Status: 403
  Content-Type: text/html
  Size: 919 B
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>403 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
Request blocked.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a config...
<BR clear="all">
```

#

```
#str(x) gives me
str(x)

List of 10
 $ url        : chr "https://services9.arcgis.com/N9p5hsImWXAccRNI/arcgis/rest/services/Nc2JKvYFoAEOFCG5JSI6/FeatureServer/4/query?f"| __truncated__
 $ status_code: int 403
 $ headers    :List of 9
  ..$ server        : chr "CloudFront"
  ..$ date          : chr "Fri, 27 Mar 2020 14:15:15 GMT"
  ..$ content-type  : chr "text/html"
  ..$ content-length: chr "919"
  ..$ connection    : chr "keep-alive"
  ..$ x-cache       : chr "Error from cloudfront"
  ..$ via           : chr "1.1 7ddf939a79757069f5b9d04b0ce928cf.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"
  ..$ x-amz-cf-pop  : chr "BLR50-C1"
  ..$ x-amz-cf-id   : chr "obYT8TG43RpvXHq8VoWYPnSYLIdSwQgf4tFkP1oshW9xtmEkSj5AJA=="
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "insensitive" "list"
 $ all_headers:List of 1
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ status : int 403
  .. ..$ version: chr "HTTP/1.1"
  .. ..$ headers:List of 9
  .. .. ..$ server        : chr "CloudFront"
  .. .. ..$ date          : chr "Fri, 27 Mar 2020 14:15:15 GMT"
  .. .. ..$ content-type  : chr "text/html"
  .. .. ..$ content-length: chr "919"
  .. .. ..$ connection    : chr "keep-alive"
  .. .. ..$ x-cache       : chr "Error from cloudfront"
  .. .. ..$ via           : chr "1.1 7ddf939a79757069f5b9d04b0ce928cf.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"
  .. .. ..$ x-amz-cf-pop  : chr "BLR50-C1"
  .. .. ..$ x-amz-cf-id   : chr "obYT8TG43RpvXHq8VoWYPnSYLIdSwQgf4tFkP1oshW9xtmEkSj5AJA=="
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "insensitive" "list"
 $ cookies    :'data.frame':    0 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ domain    : logi(0) 
  ..$ flag      : logi(0) 
  ..$ path      : logi(0) 
  ..$ secure    : logi(0) 
  ..$ expiration: 'POSIXct' num(0) 
  ..$ name      : logi(0) 
  ..$ value     : logi(0) 
 $ content    : raw [1:919] 3c 21 44 4f ...
 $ date       : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2020-03-27 14:15:15"
 $ times      : Named num [1:6] 0 0.000159 0.000164 0.000517 0.004218 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "redirect" "namelookup" "connect" "pretransfer" ...
 $ request    :List of 7
  ..$ method    : chr "GET"
  ..$ url       : chr "https://services9.arcgis.com/N9p5hsImWXAccRNI/arcgis/rest/services/Nc2JKvYFoAEOFCG5JSI6/FeatureServer/4/query?f"| __truncated__
  ..$ headers   : Named chr "application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "Accept"
  ..$ fields    : NULL
  ..$ options   :List of 2
  .. ..$ useragent: chr "libcurl/7.64.1 r-curl/4.3 httr/1.4.1"
  .. ..$ httpget  : logi TRUE
  ..$ auth_token: NULL
  ..$ output    : list()
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "write_memory" "write_function"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "request"
 $ handle     :Class 'curl_handle' <externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "response"
```

Comment: Check your variable names, and inspect the intermediate data at each step. For example, should second line be `fromJSON(url)`.

Comment: my bad... it should be url. Did not change while copy pasting. Now updated

Comment: How does x look (eg `str(x)` ) after running `fromJSON` function? What is error message?

Comment: Also, maybe you want to get coronavirus data from alternative sources, big list here: https://github.com/soroushchehresa/awesome-coronavirus

Comment: I have added ```print(x)``` and ```str(x)``` to the main body. My task is to get it from this particular source alone.

Comment: JHU has a github repo with a downloadable database: https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19

Comment: Perhaps they require a key. Looking at the the blog post I see `Further, all the data collected and displayed is made freely available, initially as google sheets, now in a GitHub repository, along with the feature layers of the dashboard, which are now included in the ESRI Living Atlas.` https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19 ... so go directly to the source!

Comment: Thanks, That works for me.